Gap between flange for popup drain and bottom of sink drain
There is a large gap above the popup drain screw-in flange and the drain hole - as shown in the photo. It is more than the thickness of the bottom of the sink.  I would like to screw this thing tightly into the sink drain hole, but that is not possible as currently set up.  One video suggested a thick layer of silicone/caulking to supplement that smallish black flange: but that is fairly unsatisfactory, both for sealing and for structural (the assembly can move around).  And this is not the place for plumber's putty, which only belongs above the sink drain to seal the popup to sink drain hole.

What is the game plan supposed to be here: how can both a non-ambiguous tight seal and a rigid placement of the pipe be achieved (preferably with standard parts on hand)?
Note there is a similar question How to deal with a pop up drain install when nut doesn't sit flush with bottom of the sink? but the answers do not provide a direct resolution

The first/accepted answer mentions a missing rubber ring. I do not have that case: I am looking at a newly opened box
The second answer describes some exotic / two days long process with many steps that including sugru. That is a process I can not follow due to complexity and duration


That drain is made for a sink with a built in overflow. Does your sink have an overflow port?  If not you need to purchase a drain for sinks without overflows.

@RMDman. You are on the right track.  I had another sink (with overflow) in it. The real issue is that the vessel sink does not have a neck below the drain, so the drain assembly was being asked to reach up too far and also without a good bite.  I will need to figure out what type of drain assembly matches that vessel sink. but in the meantime my other bathroom can use this other "with neck" assembly just fine.

I was trying this on a vessel sink with no neck below the drain.  I was tearing my hair out on an unsolvable problem.  Total fail.

I had another sink lying around that has an actual "neck" below the drain - as shown in the red rectangle.  This popup drain assembly "just works" with it.

It is holding water just fine here:

